# Meteor JS Jade template does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, meteor, pug

I tried this package https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/ easy search using this sample code

```
<template name="searchBox">
    {{> esInput index="players" placeholder="Search..." }}

    <ul>
        {{#esEach index="players"}}
           <li>Name of the player: {{name}}</li>
        {{/esEach}}
    </ul>
 </template>
```

and convert it to jade

```
template(name="searchBox")
  +esInput index="players" placeholder="Search..." 
  ul
    esEach index="players"
      li Name of the player: {{name}}
```

If I used the html format the search works but when I used the jade format no errors but search will not display. Did I convert the html to jade properly? Any ideas why jade does not work?

Comment: I've never used jade in Meteor, but shouldn't `esEach` be `+esEach`? I'm guessing `esEach` is interpreted as an element.

Comment: @PeppeL-G Good Catch! Can you make it an answer so that I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`esEach` should be `+esEach`. And this is now at least 30 character.